# IBM DataPower LTPA

Tags: ltpa

Can I generate the LTPA2 Token Key without the need for any of IBM products like IBM WebSphere Application Server?

I'm trying to use datapower to generate LTPA token (based on authenticating user by username and password) and then reply back to the client with the LTPA Token. The subsequent requests from the client would have the LTPA token and IBM datapower would authenticate the requests based on the extracted LTPA token and then forward the request to a backend web server that is not IBM webspher server.

The flow is as per the below:

Client ―> DataPower ―> Backend Server (not IBM Server)

1. The client submits a request with the credentials (username/password)
   in the authorisation header.
2. DataPower AAA, extracts the identity (Authroization http header with
   username/password) and authenticate the user
3. DataPower Generates the LTPA2 token in the post processing step and
   send it back to the client.
4. The client sends a request to access a protected resource protected by
   DataPower AAA policy.
5. DataPower checks the request for LTPA2 token
6. If the token is valid, IBM datapower forwards the request to the
   backend server.

If we don’t have IBM WebSphere Application Server, is there any way to
generate the LTPA Key file?

Comment: This document show some iseas about creating LTPA in DataPower. Hope it helps: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038292

Answer (score 0):

To generate an LTPA token you must have LTPA key. One way to obtain such key is to go to any Worklight installation [Worklight server because I am familiar with and tested it] and copy the LTPA.key file. Supply this to Datapower in post processing step and you are done.

That is all you have to do to generate LTPA token from Datapower. Let me know if you face any issue.

- Ajitabh